# Gstreamer autoplugging: create demux on "have-type"

Tags: python, gstreamer

I'm trying to use the `typefind` element to choose the right type of demux at runtime. If I create the demux before playback and link it upon receiving "have-type" signal, everything works fine. For example:

```py
import sys
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst
from gi.repository import GObject

def on_message(bus, message, loop):
    mtype = message.type

    if mtype == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        print("End of stream")
        loop.quit()

    return True


n = 0
def new_sample(sink, data):
    global n
    n += 1
    #print('new-sample')
    sample = sink.emit('pull-sample')
    return Gst.FlowReturn.OK


Gst.init(None)

loop = GObject.MainLoop()

pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()
src = Gst.ElementFactory.make('splitfilesrc')
typefind = Gst.ElementFactory.make('typefind')
demux = Gst.ElementFactory.make('avidemux')
sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make('appsink')

src.set_property('location', sys.argv[1])

pipeline.add(src)
pipeline.add(typefind)
pipeline.add(demux)
pipeline.add(sink)

if not src.link(typefind):
    print('Could not link src to typefind.')
    exit(1)

def demux_pad_added(element, pad):
    stream = pad.query_caps(None).to_string()
    print('Found stream: {}'.format(stream))
    result = pad.link(sink.get_static_pad('sink'))
    if result != Gst.PadLinkReturn.OK:
        print()
        print('Could not link demux to sink.')
        loop.quit()

sink.set_property('emit-signals', True)
sink.set_property('sync', False)
sink.connect('new-sample', new_sample, None)

def have_type(typefind, probability, caps):
    print('have-type:', caps.to_string())
    demux.connect('pad-added', demux_pad_added)
    if not typefind.link(demux):
        print('Could not link typefind to demux.')
        exit(1)
typefind.connect('have-type', have_type)

bus = pipeline.get_bus()
bus.add_signal_watch()
bus.connect('message', on_message, loop)

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
try:
    loop.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print()
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
print('total:', n)
```

If I run this I get something like:

```
$ python foo.py foo.avi
have-type: video/x-msvideo
Found stream: video/x-h264, variant=(string)itu, framerate=(fraction)50/1, max-input-size=(int)1048576, width=(int)1728, height=(int)3072, stream-format=(string)byte-stream,
alignment=(string)au
^C
total: 12144
```

Now If I move demux creation inside the "have-type" callback:

```py
import sys
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst
from gi.repository import GObject

def on_message(bus, message, loop):
    mtype = message.type

    if mtype == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        print("End of stream")
        loop.quit()

    return True


n = 0
def new_sample(sink, data):
    global n
    n += 1
    #print('new-sample')
    sample = sink.emit('pull-sample')
    return Gst.FlowReturn.OK


Gst.init(None)

loop = GObject.MainLoop()

pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()
src = Gst.ElementFactory.make('splitfilesrc')
typefind = Gst.ElementFactory.make('typefind')
#demux = Gst.ElementFactory.make('avidemux')
sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make('appsink')

src.set_property('location', sys.argv[1])

pipeline.add(src)
pipeline.add(typefind)
#pipeline.add(demux)
pipeline.add(sink)

if not src.link(typefind):
    print('Could not link src to typefind.')
    exit(1)

def demux_pad_added(element, pad):
    stream = pad.query_caps(None).to_string()
    print('Found stream: {}'.format(stream))
    result = pad.link(sink.get_static_pad('sink'))
    if result != Gst.PadLinkReturn.OK:
        print()
        print('Could not link demux to sink.')
        loop.quit()

sink.set_property('emit-signals', True)
sink.set_property('sync', False)
sink.connect('new-sample', new_sample, None)

def have_type(typefind, probability, caps):
    print('have-type:', caps.to_string())
    demux = Gst.ElementFactory.make('avidemux')
    pipeline.add(demux)
    demux.connect('pad-added', demux_pad_added)
    if not typefind.link(demux):
        print('Could not link typefind to demux.')
        exit(1)
typefind.connect('have-type', have_type)

bus = pipeline.get_bus()
bus.add_signal_watch()
bus.connect('message', on_message, loop)

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
try:
    loop.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print()
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
print('total:', n)
```

Notice only the two `demux = ...` and `pipeline.add(demux)` lines have been moved into the callback, but this pipeline doesn't seem to do anything:

```
$ python foo.py foo.avi
have-type: video/x-msvideo
^C
total: 0
```

I could probably create all possible demux'es beforehand and link the one I want in the callback but I was wondering why this doesn't work and whether I could make it work like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small detail here. Since you add the demuxer late to the pipeline it is still in `NULL` state because it did not receive the state change to PLAYING from the pipeline. It needs to be in PAUSED/PLAYING state to actually do anything.

If I'm not mistaken it should work if you modify your code to put your demuxer into PLAYING state after you hooked it up..:

```py
    [..]
    demux = Gst.ElementFactory.make('avidemux')
    pipeline.add(demux)
    demux.connect('pad-added', demux_pad_added)
    if not typefind.link(demux):
        print('Could not link typefind to demux.')
        exit(1)
    demux.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
typefind.connect('have-type', have_type)
[..]
```

Comment: This is it exactly. Thanks!